# How to get the width and height of an Base64 image

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to create a helper function where I will pass the Base64 image and it will return the width and height of that image. I have tried with the below approach, but it always returns null. Somehow it is not updating the width and height variables.

How can I get the width and height of the image?

```
getDimensions(image : string){
   var width : number = null;
   var height : number = null;

   var img = new Image();
   img.src = image;

   img.onload = () => {
      width = img.width;
      height = img.width;
   }

   return {width, height};
}

let dimensions : any = this.getDimensions(base64Image);
```

Comment: onload is async, so the values of width/height wont be assigned until after the return. What you would have to do is accept a callback and call that in `onload` or return a promise.

Comment: @Han Yolo, can be able share a a piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make the function async:

```
getDimensions(image : string){
   return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{

       var img = new Image();
       img.src = image;

       img.onload = () => {
          resolve({width: img.width, height: img.height})
      }

   })
}


let dimesions : Promise = await this.getDimensions(base64Image);
```

I would suggest trying a tutorial on promises and async programming.