# How to get width / height of a base64 image in deno?

Tags: typescript, supabase, deno

This is a repeat of this question: [Get image width and height from the Base64 code in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774928/get-image-width-and-height-from-the-base64-code-in-javascript) but I am asking with regards to deno. Deno does not have the `new Image()` that is used in all the solutions I have read. I intend on doing this in an edge function so reduced dependencies is important. A few things I have considered:

- https://github.com/DjDeveloperr/skia_canvas
  But the edge enviornment I'm working in does not allow write access which is required to use this.
- https://github.com/matmen/ImageScript
  But I don't know the relevant deno http address to import it from

Is there a way to do this without a package or to do it simply using some built-in package?

Comment: Maybe you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327959/get-height-and-width-dimensions-from-a-base64-encoded-png-image) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63969580/how-to-get-the-width-and-height-of-an-base64-image).

Comment: is deno capable to creating an element? I'm not sure how it works exactly. But the new Image() is not available so that solution wouldn't work here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get image width & height without external libraries, you need to parse the image header. If you're only dealing with few image type you could easly avoid using third-party libs.

For example for parsing a png image width & height from a base64 encoded image you could do it like this:

```
import { decode } from "https://deno.land/std/encoding/base64.ts"

const pngImageb64 = /* some png image in base64 */

const pngImage = decode(pngImageb64);
const dataView = new DataView(pngImage.buffer);
// The width and height are 4-byte integers starting 
// at byte offset 16 and 20, respectively.
const width = dataView.getUint32(16);
const height = dataView.getUint32(20);
```

Ref: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html

> Width and height give the image dimensions in pixels. They are 4-byte
> integers. Zero is an invalid value. The maximum for each is 2^31

---

For **jpeg** it's a bit harder since the dimensions are stored in the Start of Frame (SOF) markers. The following should work for most cases (only tested it in a few jpegs)

```js
const jpegImageb64 = /* some jpeg image in base64 */

const jpegImage = decode(jpegImageb64);
const dataView = new DataView(jpegImage.buffer);

let width, height;
for (let i = 0; i < dataView.byteLength - 9; i++) {  // - 9 prevent out-of-bounds access
    if (dataView.getUint16(i) === 0xFFC0 || dataView.getUint16(i) === 0xFFC2) {
      height = dataView.getUint16(i + 5);
      width = dataView.getUint16(i + 7);
      break;
  }
}
```

Other possible solutions:

- [Parsing JPEG SOS Marker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26715684/parsing-jpeg-sos-marker)
- [Getting Image size of JPEG from its binary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2517854/getting-image-size-of-jpeg-from-its-binary)

---

To detect the image type so you know which parser to use, you have to read the first bytes of the image, you could use [`file-type`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/file-type) lib for it (after decoding base64)

See https://github.com/sindresorhus/file-type/blob/5c42f8057f056fe41cbe4bffb53f56987d02e909/core.js#L238-L249 for detecting jpeg yourself.

---

Depending on the image type you're dealing with, it could be more complicated, if you support a wide variety of image formats I would recommend using a library such as `sharp` for parsing that data.